# What happens if fewer than three team members are available?

Tags: tales-from-the-borderlands

At the end of chapter 5, you get to assemble a team. I had nearly everyone available, thanks to my actions in game.

What happens if I piss everyone off and nobody is left at the end? Does the final mission still go ahead? How does it change without them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever your choices will be in the game, August and Athena will always join your team in the end. It is impossible to not have them during the final selection.

However, if you only have those two, Zer0 will come back and (reluctantly) join your team. In any cases, you will always have at least three choices during the final mission.

People in this [thread](https://www.telltalegames.com/community/discussion/101393/episode-5-bad-premature-ending-no-vault-hunters) also seem to confirm it.